# add new row in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

**UPDATE**

from this i bind gridview

```
Public Function uplif() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        gridvieew1.Visible = True

        Try

            dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(1) {New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)),
                                                   New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String))}
            Dim Content As String = Request.Form(textbox1.UniqueID)
            For Each row As String In Content .Split(ControlChars.Lf)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row) Then
                    dt.Rows.Add()
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    For Each cell As String In row.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
                        If i > 1 Then
                            labelmessage.Text = "More than 2 columns not Allowed !!"
                            textbox1.Text = ""
                        Else
                            If cell.Trim() = "" Then
                                cell = "0"
                            End If
                            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell
                            i += 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
             gridvieew1.DataSource = dt
             gridvieew1.DataBind()

        Catch Ex As Exception
            labelmessage.CssClass = "alertNo"
            labelmessage.Text = Ex.Message
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function

  Protected Sub PasteToGridView(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        uplif()

    End Sub
```

now when i try to add new row like this

```
Private Sub AddNewRowToGrid()
        Dim dt As DataTable = uplif()
        Dim NewRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dt.Rows.Add(NewRow)
         gridvieew1.DataSource = dt
         gridvieew1.DataBind()
    End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddNewRowToGrid()
    End Sub
```

this shows same output like add new row and replace previous data which is already in gridview and also this shows an error 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

after click on add new row

```
ID Name
```

where as i want like this

```
ID Name
1  abc
2  def
(here new empty row when click on button )
```

Comment: this is vb code. why you have added c# tag here?

Comment: Every time you click on your Button1, a brand new DataTable is created and it is binded to your DGV. `If dt.Columns.Count = 0 Then`is not necessary, because it is always true.

Comment: so i remove this line If dt.Columns.Count = 0 Then?

Comment: do not create a new DataTable. Use the exsisting one

Comment: please check update question

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in a comment to your post, the problem is in these two lines:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
...
gridview1.DataSource = dt
```

That creates a brand new `DataTable` and binds the grid view to it.  You don't copy data over, and you don't alter the existing gridview's table.

The correct fix here would be to get the `DataTable` from the gridview's DataSource and make any changes you need to to that.  Don't create a new `DataTable`.

Comment: yes i do this i use existing datatable but this shows same please check update question

Answer (score 0):

Get the already assigned DataSource and then add the Row. Do not add columns as it will be already present in your datasource

```
 Private Sub AddNewRowToGrid()
        Dim dt As gridview1.DataSource       
        Dim NewRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dt.Rows.Add(NewRow)
        gridview1.DataSource = dt
        gridview1.DataBind()
    End Sub

 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddNewRowToGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: this shows an error .. Error 126 Type 'gridview1.DataSource' is not defined.